# UML diagram for interacting state machines

Tags: uml, state-machine, sequence-diagram, state-diagram

I have two applications which communicate with each other by sending text messages over TCP. I would like to document their state-machine controlled communication using UML diagrams. I could draw two state machine diagrams (one for each program), but I think it would be better to "connect" or "merge" these state diagrams somehow, in order to show the interaction of the programs. How can I achieve this? Or should I draw sequence diagrams for every possible communication scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a sequence diagram annotated with state changes, as shown in the following picture:

http://state-machine.com/attachments/sequence_with_states.png

Of course, a sequence diagram shows only a specific scenario of interactions, but if you choose the exchanged events carefully, you can show the most interesting interactions. Of course, you can create many such sequence diagrams to show also exceptional conditions, etc.